# How do create Vendor Bill in NetSuite using REST API?

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

How do create Vendor Bill in NetSuite by REST API call? Also, supply tax which I want as per my requirement. Currently, I am facing the issue that NetSuite Auto applies tax based on Vendor's country and state. But I want to override that tax details. Due to this issue, I am getting high total amount than the actual Vendor Bill.

Please help me out, if anyone has done the same thing.

I have followed the official document of NetSuite REST API. This is not of much use to me as they did not mention the full detail of the POST call. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to undertake further tests with the following, but depending on the form you are using and the mandatory fields it contains, the payload for a vendor bill would look something like this:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "id": "1234"
    },
    "externalid" : "EXAMPLE-001",
    "tranDate": "2023-3-19",
    "location": 15,
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "id": 4650
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "Description": "ADDING AN ITEM EXAMPLE",
                "amount": 20                
            }
        ]
    },
    "taxDetails": {
        "items": [
            {
              (REFER TO THIS LINK FOR PARAMETERS: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2022.1/index.html#/definitions/vendorBill-taxDetailsElement)
            }
         ]
    },
    "taxDetailsOverride": "true" 
}
```

Hope this helps.